# Booking ETS Platinum class trains more than 24 hours in advance

Tags: trains, bookings, malaysia, kuala-lumpur, ipoh

I'm looking to book tickets on an [ETS Platinum](http://www.ktmb.com.my/ETS.html) train service from Kuala Lumpur (KL Sentral) to Ipoh.  The [official timetable](http://intranet4.ktmb.com.my/ktmb/uploads/files/train%20schedule/ETS/2019/20191201%20Website%20Jadual%20Tren%20ETS%20v1_1.pdf) shows a number of Platinum services (EPxxxx) running daiy; however, while other ETS services show up on booking portals, none of the Platinum trains do, even on the [official site](https://www.ktmb.com.my/).

However, [this random site](https://theipohguide.com/ets-business-class/) says that Platinum bookings for the KL-Ipoh sector open only 24 hours before departure.  I can't find confirmation of this in any even semi-official source.  **Is it really impossible to book Platinum tickets more than a day in advance?**  (And if so, why!?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: turns out the 24-hour limit is in place because all ETS Platinum trains **continue past Ipoh to Penang/Padang Besar**.  So you can book well in advance if you're going further than Ipoh, but they don't want people traveling only to Ipoh to hog all the seats.

In the end, as we'd been told there was plenty of space and we had no trouble reserving the previous day.  The train *did* fill up pretty well, even on an off-peak weekday, so don't leave the booking until too late.